# Add wait to checkbox select

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I use this code with Java and Selenium to select a checkbox.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(inputId));
System.out.println("Selecting checkbox value " + value + " using id locator " + inputId);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Is it possible to add wait listener for the check button to be clickable? Sometimes the code fails with exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Comment: What do you mean? Aren't you talking about `FluentWait` waiters?

Comment: Yes, how I can use it into this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more natural way would be:

```java
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(inputId)));
System.out.println("Selecting checkbox value " + value + " using id locator " + inputId);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

`until` method will automatically return located element so that no need to have extra code.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add wait until the element is clickable.
Like this:

```
public void waitForElementToBeClickable(By element) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
}
```

Then:

```
waitForElementToBeClickable(By.id(inputId));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(inputId));
System.out.println("Selecting checkbox value " + value + " using id locator " + inputId);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```